# Kernel trick derivation: why this simplification is incorrect?

Tags: kernel

I am trying to derive kernel trick from linear regression, and I have a mistake in the very end, which leads to an expression too simple.

### Basic linear regression

For a basic linear regression (with no regularisation for simplicity), let ${\bf x_i}$ be row-vectors of data of length $p$ (for instance, each coordinate $x_{i,j}$ might be the value of expression of gene $j$ in patient $i$).

Let the corresponding data matrix $X = \begin{pmatrix} {\bf x_1} \\ {\bf x_2} \\ ... \\ {\bf x_n} \end{pmatrix}$ be $n$ x $p$ matrix of data (e.g. n - number of patients, p - number of genes), ${\bf w}$ be the vector of weights (e.g. weight $w_j$ is the contribution of expression of gene $j$ to a patient's body mass index).

In case of a regular regression we would be trying to estimate body mass index of patient $i$ as:

$h({\bf x_i}) = {\bf x_i} {\bf w}$

Fitting this to measurements vector ${\bf y}^T = (y_1, ..., y_n)$ would imply minimization of sum of square errors:

$\hat{\bf w} = \underset{\bf w}{\arg \min} ({\bf y} - X {\bf w })^{T} ({\bf y} - X {\bf w})$ which results in:

${\hat{\bf w}} = (X^T X)^{-1} \cdot X^T{\bf y}$

### Kernel regression

Now, we replace $n$ x $p$ matrix $X$ of basic features with an $n$ x $P$ matrix $\Phi = \begin{pmatrix} {\bf \varphi(x_1)} \\ {\bf \varphi(x_2)} \\ ... \\ {\bf \varphi(x_n)} \end{pmatrix}$ of feature maps, where, again, each row $\bf \varphi(x_i)$ corresponds to a single patient, but now has a different, possibly infinite, length $P$ instead of $p$.

Accordingly, our weights vector $\bf w$ is now going to be $P$-vector instead of $p$-vector.

Hence, our estimate function of BMI $h({\bf \varphi({\bf x_i})}) = {\bf \varphi(x_i)} \cdot {\bf w} = {\bf \varphi(x_i)} \cdot (\Phi^T \Phi)^{-1} \cdot \Phi^T{\bf y}$.

Now we change the representation of our [pseudo-inverse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse): $(\Phi^T \Phi)^{-1} \Phi^T = \Phi^T (\Phi \Phi^T)^{-1}$.

This results in a different representation of $h({\bf \varphi({\bf x_i})})$:

$h({\bf \varphi({\bf x_i})}) = {\bf \varphi(x_i)} \cdot \Phi^T (\Phi \Phi^T)^{-1} {\bf y}$

### My question

What I don't quite understand here is the following.

Denote matrix $\Phi \Phi^T = K$.

Consider expression $h({\bf \varphi({\bf x_i})}) = {\bf \varphi(x_i)} \cdot \Phi^T (\Phi \Phi^T)^{-1} {\bf y}$.

The multiplier ${\bf \phi(x_i)}\Phi^T$ is essentially the i-th row of our matrix $K$.

The other multiplier is $(\Phi \Phi^T)^{-1} {\bf y} = K^{-1} y$.

What happens, if we multiply i-th row of a matrix $K$ by its inverse? We should get a one-hot vector $(0, 0, ..., \underbrace{1}_{i-th position}, ..., 0)$, right?

So I assume $h({\bf \varphi({\bf x_i})}) = (0, 0, ..., \underbrace{1}_{i-th position}, ..., 0) \cdot {\bf y} = y_i$.

I must be wrong somewhere, but I cannot find mistakes in my reasoning.

The correct answer does not allow for such a simplification and instead takes a more general form $h({\bf \varphi({\bf x_i})}) = \sum \limits_{j=1}^n \alpha_j {\bf \phi(x_i)} {\bf \phi(x_j)}$, where vector ${\bf \alpha} = (\Phi \Phi^T)^{-1} {\bf y}$.

Comment: Cross Validated seems a much more appropriate place to ask this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now we change the representation of our pseudo-inverse matrix
> $(\Phi^T\Phi)^{-1} \Phi^T = \Phi^T (\Phi \Phi^T)^{-1}$.

The above **cannot be done** as different representations rely on different assumptions about column rank and row rank and in fact are inequivalent in general.

> In particular, when $A$ has **linearly independent columns** (and thus
> matrix $A^{*}A$ is invertible), $A^{+}$ can be computed as
> $A^{+}=\left(A^{*}A\right)^{-1}A^{*}$.
>
> This particular pseudoinverse constitutes a **left inverse**, since, in
> this case, $A^{+}A=I$.
>
> When $A$ has **linearly independent rows** (matrix $AA^{*}$ is
> invertible), $A^{+}$ can be computed as
> $A^{+}=A^{*}\left(AA^{*}\right)^{-1}$.
>
> This is a **right inverse**, as $AA^{+}=I$.

**The left and right pseudo-inverses coincide only in special cases (eg when actual matrix $A$ is indeed invertible).**

References:
[Definition of Moore-Penrose Pseudo-Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition)

Comment: Nicos, thank you for your answer and sorry for my late response. You are right, if $N > p$, $\Phi^T \Phi$ matrix is not full-rank, and cannot be inverted. Moreover, even if $\Phi^T \Phi$ is full rank, $\Phi \Phi^T$ might not be.

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

After additional research I found out that my general direction was right, but required a more elaborate approach.

Indeed, if $P \gg n$, $\Phi^T \Phi$ is a non-full rank matrix with lots of zero eigenvalues, thus its inverse $(\Phi^T \Phi)^{-1}$ cannot exist.

However, in order to overcome this problem, we can add a Tikhonov regularisation term: $(\lambda I + \Phi^T \Phi)$, effectively increasing all the matrix  eigenvalues by $\lambda$ and thus making it invertible.

After that we apply [Woodbury-Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) to invert the regularized matrix and express the solution of kernel ridge regression through kernel matrix $K$:

$h(\varphi({\bf x_i})) = \varphi({\bf x_i}) \cdot (\lambda I + \Phi^T \Phi)^{-1} \Phi^T \cdot {\bf y} = \varphi({\bf x_i}) \cdot \Phi^T (\Phi \Phi^T + \lambda I)^{-1} \cdot {\bf y} = $

$= K_i \cdot (K + \lambda I)^{-1} \cdot {\bf y}$

So, yes, if not for the regularisation term, this formula would've just selected $y_i$ from outputs vector as an estimate of $h(\varphi(x_i))$. However, addition of regularisation to the kernel matrix complicates this expression.

Anyway, we end up with an explicit solution of KRR through kernel matrix $K$ and regression outputs ${\bf y}$ and through mathematical magic avoid (possibly infinite-dimensional) feature space vectors $\varphi({\bf x_i})$.

---

References:

- https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/01/06/kernel-gp-regression/ - details on Woodbury-Sherman-Morrison by Gregory Gundersen
- [https://web2.qatar.cmu.edu/~gdicaro/10315-Fall19/additional/welling-notes-on-kernel-ridge.pdf](https://web2.qatar.cmu.edu/%7Egdicaro/10315-Fall19/additional/welling-notes-on-kernel-ridge.pdf) - notes of Max Welling on KRR
- https://www.quora.com/Are-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-unchanged-if-a-constant-is-added-to-each-diagonal-element - why L2 regularisation makes matrix non-singular